# AdMob used with iOS 6 crashes the app (unrecognized selector)

Tags: ios, crash, admob, selector, unrecognized-selector

I'm using AdMob 6.2.1 in my app which runs under iOS 6 only.
I've followed google instructions and everything is working well when running on the simulator and on my iPhone 5.

But, when submitting to Apple the app, i get it refused and the crash log indicates the following:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3abcb3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x392d695e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3abcef2c -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 180
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3abcd648 ___forwarding___ + 388
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3ab25204 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   Dus                             0x000d39f4 -[GADObjectPrivate loadPrivateRequest:autoRefresh:] (GADObjectPrivate.m:402)
6   Dus                             0x000d5454 -[GADObjectPrivate loadRequest:] (GADObjectPrivate.m:827)
7   Dus                             0x000d2f20 -[GADBannerView loadRequest:] (GADBannerView.m:271)
8   Dus                             0x000b57cc -[DMViewController viewDidLoad] (DMViewController.m:131)
```

I don't understand why it is working for me and crashing with Apple staff.

I had added `-ObjC` (both to Debug and Release) to `Other Linker Flags` in `Build Settings`.

Here is the block code where the crash occurs:

```
bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin];

bannerView.adUnitID = @"MYBANNERID";
[bannerView setRootViewController:self];
[bannerView setDelegate:self];
bannerView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, bannerView.center.y);

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

[bannerView loadRequest:request]; //CRASHES HERE
[self.view addSubview:bannerView];
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Interesting that issue usually comes because of a lack of the ObjC flag. What is your base SDK set to? Also did Apple give you any other info as to what devices/iOS version they saw that crash on?

Comment: My base SDK is set to "Latest iOS (iOS 6.0)". Apple said that they tried the app onto iPhone and iPad (my app is only targeting iPhones) with Wifi and carrier network too, but keeps crashing...

Comment: did you find the solution. my application wont rejected. but it crashes.

Comment: Unfortunately the only solution i found is using a @try-catch block. If the exception is caught, then the banner is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Place request into `ViewDidAppear` method.

Comment: thank you, but what's differ with ViewDidLoad? In google doc available here: [link]http://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals they request in ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should addSubview: when adView is ready. ie: inside admob's -adViewDidReceiveAd:. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As this issue is related about lacking of -ObjC linker flag,
please check your archive schema and be sure it's using release profile. 
(If this is an old project you might create a distribution profile before (apple did that way in examples) and archive might use that profile)